# Dissatisfactional construction time

Tags: java, optimization, drools, heuristics, optaplanner

I am still using the OptaPlanner (Version 6.2) to optimize a chained planning problem which is similar to the VehicleRoutingExample. My planning entities have a planning variable which is another planning entity. The scores are HardSoftScores, which are calculated with an IncrementalScore.

The construction time (of the Construction Heuristic) takes too long. At the moment it needs about 15 minutes to initialize a solution of 1800 entities.  The average calculation count is over 1000 counts per second, so the problem shouldn’t be the score calculation.

I already tried different configurations with the benchmarker, but there was no huge difference.

Here is my benchmarked Solverconfiguration:

```
<solver>
  <solutionClass>...Solution</solutionClass>
  <entityClass>>...Standstill</entityClass>
  <entityClass>...DriveJob</entityClass>
  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
    <incrementalScoreCalculatorClass>...IncrementalScoreCalculator</incrementalScoreCalculatorClass>
    <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
  </scoreDirectorFactory>
  <constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
  </constructionHeuristic>
  <localSearch>
    <termination>
      <unimprovedStepCountLimit>100</unimprovedStepCountLimit>
    </termination>
    <acceptor>
      <entityTabuSize>5</entityTabuSize>
      <simulatedAnnealingStartingTemperature>1hard/1000soft</simulatedAnnealingStartingTemperature>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
      <acceptedCountLimit>4</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
  </localSearch>
</solver>
```

What can I do to reduce the construction heuristic (CH) time?

Would it make sense to configure selectors for the CH and the local search phase?

Or could there be a problem in my POJO classes/domain description?

If any other information is needed I will provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Limited selection" if you have 1 planning variable per entity.

If you have multiple planning variables per entity, take a look at not defaulting to cartesian product in the CH, which can be done with the advanced CH configurations (see CH chapter in docs).

Comment: And also try the CH type FIRST_FEASIBLE_FIT(_DECREASING)